# Table row border overlapping outer table border

Tags: css

I have a table with 2 columns and I want each row to have a gray `border-top`, a border down the middle separating the columns and the overall table to have a black border. However, the border on the table rows and the `border-right` on the first column of each row is overlapping the overall tables border. How can I resolve this?

```css
table {
  width:350px;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  table-layout:fixed;
  border:2px solid black;
  text-align:center;
}
  tr {
    border-top:2px solid #cecece;
  }
    thead tr {
      border-top:none;
    }
    th:first-child, td:first-child {
      border-right:2px solid #cecece;
    }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Heading 1</th>
      <th>Heading 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Col 1 Row 1</td>
      <td>Col 2 Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Col 1 Row 2</td>
      <td>Col 2 Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Col 1 Row 3</td>
      <td>Col 2 Row 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `table` element in a `div` and add border to the `div` element instead of the `table` element.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 350px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

tr {
  border-top: 2px solid #cecece;
}

thead tr {
  border-top: none;
}

th:first-child,
td:first-child {
  border-right: 2px solid #cecece;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Heading 1</th>
        <th>Heading 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Col 1 Row 1</td>
        <td>Col 2 Row 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col 1 Row 2</td>
        <td>Col 2 Row 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col 1 Row 3</td>
        <td>Col 2 Row 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```